# ffmpeg hls recording the duration is float instead of integer

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to record rtsp stream using the following command in `.m3u8` format.

```
~/bin/ffmpeg -r 15 -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov -codec copy -hls_list_size 65535 -hls_time 2 -g 2 "./1/live.m3u8"
```

The above working fine with older version of ffmpeg(<3.0) and the m3u8 file content is like,

**live.m3u8** with old ffmpeg

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:2,
live0.ts
#EXTINF:2,
live1.ts
#EXTINF:2,
live2.ts
#EXTINF:0,
live3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Note the duration is integer.

But when I build the new ffmpeg3.0 and run the same command the duration is changed to flot some thing like,

**live.m3u8** with new ffmpeg3.0

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live0.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live1.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live2.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live3.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
live4.ts
#EXTINF:3.875000,
live5.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I need to generate the `ts` file with duration as integer variable with ffmpeg 3.0.

Why this happening in ffmpeg 3.0  where as it working fine in older version?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with HLS version 3 the `EXTINF` durations are expressed as floating-point values. They are required to be integers only for versions 2 and prior.

Comment: So using ffmpeg 3.0 can I use HLS 2 or prior.

Comment: @Haris I don't see any option. In any case it shouldn't make any difference seeing how both of your examples use version 3